# Is vcpkg installing debug or release version of the library?

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, qt-creator, vcpkg

How can I check if vcpkg installed debug/release version of a library?

I'm on macOS Monterey but I guess this applies to other OS also.

I did `vcpkg install qt5` and after a few hours it looks like it installed everything (almost).

After adding the kit from vcpkg on QtCreator, I can build/run a simple Qt based project in release mode but in debug mode it fails with:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

vcpkg install both versions. Qt IDE integration however works only for release builds unless you are allowed to specify a qt.conf file to use for customized lookup. Typically IDE integrations just look for qmake without any way to customize it... which only allows one build config to work in vcpkg